# AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'DataFrame'. The syntax is correct

Tags: json, python-3.x, pandas

I was testing this code snippet

```
import pandas as pd
userInput ={
    'Principal':1000, 
    'terms':15,
    'age':33,
    'Gender':1,
    'weekend':1,
    'Bechalor':0,
    'High School or Below':1,
    'college':0
    }
print(pd.DataFrame(userInput))
```

I am new to python and I am not able to understand this Traceback sequence
It is given the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/testing 123 check/json.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
  File "C:\Users\Shaswat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 55, in <module>
    from pandas.core.api import (
  File "C:\Users\Shaswat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\api.py", line 24, in <module>
    from pandas.core.groupby import Grouper, NamedAgg
  File "C:\Users\Shaswat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pandas.core.groupby.generic import (  # noqa: F401
  File "C:\Users\Shaswat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\generic.py", line 44, in <module>
    from pandas.core.frame import DataFrame
  File "C:\Users\Shaswat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 88, in <module>
    from pandas.core.generic import NDFrame, _shared_docs
  File "C:\Users\Shaswat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 5, in <module>
    import json
  File "E:/testing 123 check\json.py", line 12, in <module>
    print(pd.DataFrame(userInput))
AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'DataFrame'
```

have I installed pandas wrong?

Comment: Try running `python -m pip install --upgrade pandas` . This will try upgrading pandas, probably solves the issue. (Otherwise, you can also uninstall and reinstall, `pip uninstall pandas` and then run `pip install pandas`)

Comment: Also make sure that there are no files called `pandas.py` in your working directory. That will mess up the import.

Comment: reinstalling didn't help, and no, there are no files called pandas.py in my working directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is dumb but
I had named my file json.py
which interfered with the callbacks
the rest was OK
also, after I corrected that there was an error as:

```
ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index
```

so then, all I had to do was pass an Index

```
print(pd.DataFrame(userInput,index=[0]))
```

Comment: that is what i have mentioned in my answer,and i got down-voted as well.lol. anyway you can pass your dictionary inside to a list directly.

Answer (score -1):

I think you will get index error if you try to pass this dictionary.

update the pandas as mentioned in the comment and pass your dictionary inside to a list

```
df = pd.DataFrame([userInput])
```